# Why edittext reload listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

I have edit text in listview and when a edit text is focus it's reload/refresh the listview.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView lv = new ListView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(lv);
        lv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
     }
}
```

and :

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
public ArrayList myItems = new ArrayList();

public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        LauncherActivity.ListItem listItem = new LauncherActivity.ListItem();
        myItems.add(listItem);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.temp, null);
    return convertView;
}

}
```

[image]

Why it's produce this ?
And How to prevent this ?

> 09-08 19:38:59.913 14702-14702/com.infinity.passwordmanager W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
>   09-08 19:39:00.044 14702-14702/com.infinity.passwordmanager W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>   09-08 19:39:00.058 14702-14702/com.infinity.passwordmanager W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   09-08 19:39:00.089 14702-14702/com.infinity.passwordmanager W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>   09-08 19:39:00.101 14702-14702/com.infinity.passwordmanager W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   09-08 19:39:00.167 14702-14702/com.infinity.passwordmanager W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
>   09-08 19:39:00.267 14702-14702/com.infinity.passwordmanager W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>   09-08 19:39:00.281 14702-14702/com.infinity.passwordmanager W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

Comment: please share the logcat when screen refreshes

Comment: What is ListItem? And your `setAdapter()` argument doesn't match the Adapter class you posted.

Comment: Log added and bad C/P

Answer (score 0):

To Log or maybe Toast what happens before or after the view click, implement

```
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
```

on your

```
MyActivity
```

But first you'll have to extend *ListActivity*, which isn't an issue since your whole Activity is occupied by a ListView.
This will get you closer to what's wrong since we are limited by the amount of information your Log is posting

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview#java